Booting Linux server
I'm having troubles booting up my Linux server. I recently encrypted a volume (/dev/sdb) and my server is no longer able to boot up.
This is what I did:
sudo cryptsetup -v luksFormat /dev/Backup_VG/Backup_LV
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/Backup_VG/Backup_LV backup
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/backup
sudo mount /dev/mapper/backup /Backup
sudo bash  -c "echo backup /dev/Backup_VG/Backup_LV none >> /etc/crypttab"

Then, I configured /etc/fstab and loaded the device:
/dev/mapper/backup /Backup ext4 nofail 0 0

I don't know where I went wrong as I'm still new with Linux.
This is what I now get when I start my Linux server:

This is what i get after waiting for 2 hours.


Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Edit your question and add more information about your Ubuntu server. Which version of Ubuntu is it running. Please specify version number in YY.MM format. Does the server has any desktop installed, or are you using the desktop version of Ubuntu as a server? Copy and paste the full /etc/crypttab and the full /etc/fstab. You can access these files by booting from a live USB.
